# Change to php.ini not reflected in client php -i

Tags: php

Using Debian 8 and PHP 7.2, I added this line in **/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini** :

```
max_input_time = 600
```

But the php client don't get it:

```
~# php -i | grep max_input_time  
max_input_time => -1 => -1
```

php.ini used by php client is ok:

```
~# php -i | grep php.ini  
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php/7.2/cli  
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
```

I test the line in many php.ini sections but result is always the same.

How to change the php client parameters ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some parameters are hardcoded for the php client.

It's written inside the php.ini for each concerned parameter, example:

```
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to 0 for the CLI SAPI
```

Parameters which are not hardcoded for php client can be modified, and it's immediatly reflected by "php -i" command.

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation

> max_input_time This sets the maximum time in seconds a script is
>   allowed to parse input data, like POST and GET.

Does it applicable to CLI? Have you tried to change another configuration, for example max_execution_time?

Comment: Same, but there is the solution in the doc : "; Note: This directive is hardcoded to 0 for the CLI SAPI"

Comment: If I change a parameter which is not hardcoded for the client, it's fine.

Comment: maybe max_input_time is also hardcoded? you might change another one, for example you error_reporting which is definitely changable

Comment: yes max_input_time is also hardcoded and some others too. Thanks you guide me to the solution.

Comment: I did but that will not help people looking for the same question. I wrote an answer with the correct response, but I have to wait 2 days to accept it as answer...

Comment: That is true. Upvoded your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should restart the service,

try : 
sudo systemctl restart php-fpm.service

Comment: It's not a fpm context. It's a cli context. fpm should use something like /etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini